# Implementation differences between ExecuteDataReader and ExecuteResultSet

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, sql-server-ce

I have a series of helper classes for data access and I try to ensure that they function as consistently as possible across all the major providers such as SQL Server, Oracle and now SQL CE.

However one thing I noticed is that if I call `ExecuteReader` on a `SqlCeCommand` as opposed to a `SqlCommand` that I don't get back a `DataReader` that I can test with `HasRows()`

Looking at the documentation it says that in order to get a `DataReader` that I can test in such a fashion I should use `ExecuteResultSet` with a `ResultSetOptions` parameter set to `ResultSetOptions.Scrollable`. The issue here is that there's no overload that takes a `CommandBehaviour` as a parameter which is what I normally do to ensure that when I dispose of the `DataReader` in my DAL classes the connection gets closed.

What is the recommended best practice here? Should I wrap my call to `ExecuteResultSet` in a `using` construct so that when the DAL code is done using it that it automatically disposes? Is there some alternative that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should just use rdr.Read(), will work will all providers.

Comment: My understanding with DataReader.Read is that it positions at the first record. Typically I want to iterate through the returned DataReader and so I'll use a while() loop. If I test the returned reader first won't I have "lost" the first record? Must test...

Comment: And I am correct in that assumption. Any other ideas? A try...catch around the while perhaps?

Comment: At the moment, I've just used a try...catch and that seems to be working okay.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Read()` method to find the data in row or column as

```
Dim dd As SqlCeDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader
Dim HasRows As Boolean = dd.Read()
If HasRows Then
    ' Datareader has rows

Else
    ' No data in Row or Column
End If
```